# Novice question concerning proper method of writing a character array using fwrite?

Tags: arrays, c, fwrite

In the abbreviated function code below, would you please tell me if there is any important difference between the two versions of `fwrite` to `stdout`?

If `*n` is a pointer to a character array and `l` is the number of characters to write, is it necessary to first copy the string and then write it with the third parameter of `1`, as in the second `fwrite` of the first `if`? Or can the copy be excluded and the second set of `fwrite` used, where the third parameter is `len`?

If it is relevant, the character array `n` is a JSON string that needs to be UTF-8.

Thank you.

```
int writeout( char *n, int l )    
  {    
    const uint32_t len = l > 0 ? l : strlen( n );    
    char msg[ len ];    
    strncpy( msg, n, len ); 
    
    if ( fwrite( &len, sizeof len, 1, stdout ) != 1    
        || fwrite( msg, sizeof msg, 1, stdout ) != 1 )    
      {
      }
    
    if ( fwrite( &len, sizeof len, 1, stdout ) != 1    
        || fwrite( n, sizeof( char ), len, stdout ) != len )    
      {
      }

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: The first one writes `sizeof msg` times more bytes than the second one. To answer the other question, no, copying is not necessary.

Comment: You have the `fwrite` parameters wrong, e.g. `size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);` The first parameter is the pointer (e.g. `msg`), the second is the size of each element in `msg` (e.g. `sizeof *msg`) the third is the number of members (elements) in `msg`, (e.g. `len`) and the final parameter is the open file stream. The last one is correct `fwrite( n, sizeof( char ), len, stdout ) != len`

Comment: @dxiv Thanks. After reading your comment, I realized that I made a mistake in copying the code over. The `fwrite` with `sizeof msg` should've had as the third argument/parameter the integer one instead of `len`. That's the part I don't understand. The first writes the copied array using the array length and count of one, compared to the seocnd that writes the length of char for a count of `len`.

Comment: @Gary [`fwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) writes `size * count` bytes regardless of the order in which you pass those two parameters. `fwrite(n, 1, len, ..)` will write the same bytes as `fwrite(n, len, 1, ...)`.

Comment: The key is the return equals the number of bytes transferred ***only when size is 1***. See [man 3 fwrite](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwrite.3.html)

Comment: @Davide C. Rankin Thanks. I was just reading that on the IBM Knowledge Center, but I didn't follow what I am to check to make sure all was written.

Comment: `fwrite` basically writes `nmemb` blocks of `size` to the file stream. So if you look at the answer from @JohnBollinger, `fwrite( n, len, 1, stdout );` writes 1-block of `len` size to `stdout` while `fwrite( n, 1, len, stdout );` writes `len` blocks of `1` to `stdout`. Both producing the same output, but with different returns.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you. As long as it is kown that `len` does not exceed the largest message that can be written to the receiving application, is it better to write one block of `len` rather than `len` blocks of 1?  Both are working equally the same as far as one can notice in the UI itself, but I'd like to code it properly.

Comment: That's really a what do you need to return to be question. When you are writing across a network, you will generally want the `size` as `1` so you can check the number of bytes actually sent. If you are just writing to a file where partial writes are not a problem, then `size` as `len` is fine. It's really a wash from the computer's standpoint (the assembly will likely be the same either way). From the programmer's standpoint, its knowing how `fwrite` works from that standpoint that allows you to pick the best ordering for the task at hand.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the explanation. This C code is on the local machine and is just writing JSON back to a browser extension. I guess either method will work, because all I need to know is whether it was 100% successful or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to copy the string to a local array before writing it with `fwrite`.  It is in fact wasteful to do so.  In your function,

```
char msg[ len ];
strncpy( msg, n, len ); 
// ...
fwrite( msg, sizeof msg, 1, stdout )
```

should be expected to produce exactly the same output as just

```
fwrite( n, len, 1, stdout );
```

.  That *probably* produces the same output as

```
fwrite( n, 1, len, stdout );
```

, too, but in that case the latter will return a different value (`len`) to the caller than the former does (1) because the second argument determines the size of unit in which `fwrite` transfers and counts data items.

Comment: Thank you. I think I follow you except for the last part about the return value. Isn't the third argument the count and the return value the number of items written which would be count when all were successful? Such that `fwrite( n, len, 1, stdout )` would return 1 and `fwrite( n, 1,len, stdout )` returns `len`. Or am I reading what you wrote backwards?

Comment: @Gary, yes, sorry, I misspoke; fixed. The *second* argument is the size of the unit. I always have to look up the argument order.